# Django query by month and year

Tags: python, django-queryset

I'm new to django-python so I need extra details. All I need is to provide monthly report in a pdf form and a yearly report that also in pdf form.

From my model.py

```
class Case(models.Model):
case_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
reference_choice = (
    ('Personal', 'Personal'),
    ('Court', 'Court'),
)
reference = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=reference_choice, null=True)
date_of_filing = models.DateField('Date of Filing (mm/dd/yyyy)*', blank=True, null=True)
official_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,)
complainant = models.CharField(max_length=150)
respondent = models.CharField(max_length=150)
case_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

On my views.py

```
class GeneratePDF(View):
model = Case
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    cases = Case.objects.filter.all()
    context = {
        'date': date,
        'cases': cases,

    }
    pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/monthly_report.html', context)
    if pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = 'monthly_report_%s.pdf' %('month')
        content = 'inline; filename="%s"' % (filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        return response
    return HttpResponse('Not Found')
```

and on my monthly_report.html

```
<div class="container mt-4">
        <table class="table-" style="width:1200px">
          <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Case Number</th>
                <th scope="col">Complainant</th>
                <th scope="col">Respondent</th>
                <th scope="col">Case Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Action Taken</th>
                <th scope="col">Remarks</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
                {% for case in cases %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ case.case_number }}</td>
                <td>{{ case.complainant }}</td>
                <td>{{ case.respondent }}</td>
                <td>{{ case.case_title }}</td>
                <td>{{ case.mediated| yesno }}</td>
                <td>{{ case.remarks }}</td>
            </tr>
                {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

On my code I only get all the data but it is not filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you should change your query to the correct filter.for example you can do this

```
cases=Case.objects.all().filter(date_of_filing = sometime)
```

Comment: cases = Case.objects.all().filter(date_of_filling__month='1') 
thank you for the idea, now all i need to play around with the codes...

Answer (score 1):

on the line `Case.objects.filter.all()` you can filter your results. however it does not seem like you are doing that?

an example:

```
from django.utils import timzeone
Case.objects.filter(date__gte=timezone.now()-timezone.timedelta(days=1))
```